# Convert PointField into JSON object

Tags: json, geojson, geodjango

Is there any way in which I can serialize POINTFIELD of GeoDjango into JSON?

I have following model

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='Company', null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Shop(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="bla")
    address = models.CharField(max_length=300, default='blabla')
    location = models.PointField(null=True, blank=True, geography=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(
        Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

and following serializer

```
class ShopSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    distance = serializers.DecimalField(
        source='distance.km', max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, required=False, read_only=True)

    # serialize('geojson', Shop.objects.all(),
    #           geometry_field='location', fields=('name', 'address'))

    class Meta:
        model = Shop
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'address', 'location', 'distance']
class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    shop_set = ShopSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'shop_set']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        shop_validated_data = validated_data.pop('shop_set')
        company = Company.objects.create(**validated_data)
        shop_set_serializer = self.fields['shop_set']
        for each in shop_validated_data:
            each['company'] = company
        shops = shop_set_serializer.create(shop_validated_data)
        return company
```

Using GeoJson I can get the response as follows

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Cosmetica",
        "address": "somewhere",
        "location": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                24.896,
                67.182
            ]
        }
    },
```

but here the point field has converted into an array. But I need it to be Json object with 2 key-value pairs as

```
location:{lat,long}
```

can anyone help please

Answer (score 1):

Why don't u use geos API?
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/gis/geos/#django.contrib.gis.geos.GEOSGeometry.coords

pnt.coords

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.